# What is the information content of a human being?

Tags: information

How much memory would we need to represent a human? How would each atom be stored as? Bytes? Something more complex?

Comment: Basically, what I'm trying to say is, could we fit all the atoms within our bodies into, let's say a 2GB USB flash drive (assuming each byte represents one atom), plug into a respawning machine, and have us re-appear again?

Comment: As currently worded, this is close to being off topic, since it deals with a clearly fictional technology which will never exist. Physics *can* answer "what is the information content of a human being?" but *not* "could this be submitted to a respawning machine?" BTW, there are something like $10^{27}$ or $10^{28}$ atoms in your body, not $2\times10^9$.

Comment: I'm with Chris on this, the wording needs work to get at the on-topic question in there.

Comment: @Chris a VTC would have been helpful ;-) Retrosaur, if and when this is edited to make the on-topic question clear, just flag it for moderator attention to request that it be reviewed for reopening.

Comment: Uh... *"if each atom was considered one byte in terms of memory?"* Why this particular prior assumption? It kind of defeats the whole purpose of the question, and coverts it into a simple counting exercise which has already been answered in the comments.

Comment: Plus, it would take rather more than one byte to represent the position and state of each atom accurately enough. I would suggest changing the wording to something like "how much memory would it take to represent a human, in high enough resolution that the person could, *in principle*, be reconstructed from the data and remain alive." Then it becomes an interesting and highly non-trivial question (to which I can probably give a reasonable answer). The "in principle" is important because it doesn't imply the existence of the probably-impossible machine required to actually do it.

Comment: @Nathaniel But what fidelity would the copy have to have to count as the same person? Perfect copying is impossible due to quantum no-cloning, and poor copying is obviously... problematic. So you have to draw a line somewhere. Where? That is, to me, a very interesting and difficult question in its own right. Yet surely it has a huge impact on an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: If you only want to store the DNA sequence, which should be enough to reproduce a human, you don't need a lot more than a few GBs if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Bernhard: if you really believe that, then identical twins are the same person.  And you'd be the same person if you were adopted by Bill Gates at the age of one.  There's a lot more to us than our genetics.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer Absolutely true. But the fact was interesting enough for me to post as a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Wikipedia page on [**orders of magnitude (data)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_%28data%29), 2 * 10$^{45}$ bits of information are required to perfectly recreate the average-sized adult male down to the quantum level on a computer.

Comment: This is calculated from the [Bekenstein bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekenstein_bound)